# Running a simple HTTPS Node JS Server on Amazon EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to create a simple https server on Amazon EC2 to test a third party API.

Here are the steps I've followed:

1. Created an Amazon EC2 instance, and opened up HTTP and HTTPS ports:

[image]

2. Created simple ssl credentials using

> openssl genrsa 2048 > privatekey.pem
>
> openssl req -new -key privatekey.pem -out csr.pem
>
> openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in csr.pem -signkey privatekey.pem -out
>   server.crt

3. Created a simple node js server

> ```
> var https = require('https');
> var fs = require('fs');
> var options = {
>   key: fs.readFileSync('./privatekey.pem'),
>   cert: fs.readFileSync('./server.crt')
> };
>
> https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
>   res.writeHead(200);
>   res.end("hello world\n");
> }).listen(8080);
> ```

When I run the server, and attempt to connect to it using url https://ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com/, I keep getting a connection refused.

A telnet test also produces:

```
Trying XX.XXX.XXX.XXX...
telnet: connect to address XX.XXX.XXX.XXX: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Can someone please tell me what I need to fix to enable https on this EC2 instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `listen(8080)` to `listen(443)` unless you have a web server listening on 443 and sending request to node on 8080.

Comment: Wow. It was really that simple. Had to run the server with sudo (received error as port number was below 1024), but not a blocker for me. Thank you so much!

Comment: I am trying the same thing but just can't seem to get it to work.  The pem and crt were made fine and are in the same directory - I logged them in the console from the server page and they are there.  I have the default EC2 security group set to https on 443.  I can run the sample nodejs server above using sudo and it runs.  But when I try and connect with https:// it just hangs.  It works fine if I remove the options and run on http with port 80.  I have no load Balancing to interfere.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I followed dpigera's steps, ran sudo, listen 443, open address in Chrome, and I get:  "NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID".  I can type "thisisunsafe" and get past this, but how do you generally solve this?